# jquery: add black border to text of certain length

Tags: jquery

Using jquery how can one add a black border around all "p" elements that surpass a certain value of characters (100)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("p").filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().length > 100;
}).css("border", "2px solid black");
```

Comment: Great answer. It's also worth noting that you may find the seperation of concerns more managable if you add a class to your p tags and style the class rather than adding styles directly to each p.

Comment: @Jamie: Yes, I also prefer using the external styles rather than applying it inline or via JS...for the ease of maintenance

Answer (score 3):

I think you should probably add a class, rather than including new inline styles.  I'll use the callback signature of `addClass` to achieve this.

I'm going to use the Sizzle `text` function (available as `$.text`) because it has markedly better performance than `$(this).text()`.

```
$('p').addClass(function() {
    return $.text([this]).length > 100 ? 'long' : '';
});
```

Then simply define a `p.long` class with whatever styles you want.

Comment: I like the form of this with the adding of the class

Comment: In my test (IE8), it did not work :( had to use the $(this).text().length form of the logical test.

Comment: @Mark Sorry, should have used an array containing the element.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/EDUms/1/).

It loops through all `p` elements, and if the content is greater than a given number of characters in length, it applies a style to that element.

Comment: That's what I was going to suggest also however I really like @Cybernate's answer here.

Comment: how would one return the first 4 "p" elements that satisfy this condition?

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this:
One way:

```
$('p').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().length > 100;
}).addClass('biggie');
```

and the css:

```
.biggie
{
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

Another way:

```
$('p').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().length > 100;
}).css({
    'border': '2px solid black'
});
```

One more way:

```
$('p').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().length > 100) $(this).css({
        'border': '2px solid black'
    });
});
```

another one:

```
$('p').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().length > 100) $(this).addClass('biggie');
});
```

One addition:  IF you want different border dependant on the text length, you can also set two classes at once with:

```
$('p').addClass(function() {
    return $(this).text().length > 100 ? 'long' : 'short';
});
```

Comment: how would one return the first 4 "p" elements that satisfy this condition?

Comment: @Praneet Sharma $('p').slice(0,4).addClass('howdy');

Comment: SO thus the last one would be $('p').slice(0,4).addClass(function() {
    return $(this).text().length > 100 ? 'long' : 'short';
}); to get the first 4 paragraphs a class based on size.

Comment: A filter of JUST the first 4 with size would be $('p').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().length > 100;
}).slice(0,4).css({
    'border': '2px solid black'
});